# How to alpha_composite() two images with different sizes (Pillow)

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

As the title says I want to use `Image.alpha_composite()` to merge two images of different sizes (800x600 and 1280x720). I want to use `Image.alpha_composite()` because my foreground image has a transparency effect but whenever I try to do this it just says the images do not match (they are a different size). I tried to resize it using `resize()` but it messes up the aspect ratio. I also tried using `paste()` to paste the smaller image onto a blank 1280x720 image but pasting the image to a transparent image does not work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You tried to paste or composite some images you aren't showing using code you aren't sharing and you'd like some help?

Comment: Sorry, kind of new to stackoverflow. The images I used are one color (the foreground one being half transparent) and I specified the size of each image so I figured there was no need to add the image to the post. As for "not showing code" I did show which functions I am using, but if that is not enough I can post full snippets of the code including those functions if that makes it easier for you to help me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, it is much easier for others to understand your question if you show the code that you attempted (but which didn't yield the desired result).

If I interpret your question correctly, one way to solve this is to pad the smaller image by pasting it onto an empty image that matches the larger one in size:

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

one = Image.new('RGBA', (128, 72), (255, 255, 255, 0))
ctx = ImageDraw.Draw(one)
ctx.ellipse((10, 10, 128-10, 72-10), (255, 192, 0))

two = Image.new('RGBA', (80, 60), (255, 255, 255, 0))
ctx = ImageDraw.Draw(two)
ctx.rectangle((4, 4, 80-4, 60-4), (192, 0, 0))

two_padded = Image.new('RGBA', one.size, (255, 255, 255, 0))
two_padded.paste(two)

result = Image.alpha_composite(one, two_padded)
result.show()
```

...`show()`s me the following result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't think about making a new image instead of using a blank png.